# Is this a compiler bug or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, constexpr, virtual-functions

This appears to have been fixed in more modern versions of Visual Studio, but I'm not sure if that means it was a bug or just undefined behavior.

Given the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Parent {
 virtual const char *name() const { return name2(); }
 virtual const char *name2() const { return "Parent"; }
};

struct Child : public Parent {
 virtual const char *name2() const { return "Child"; }
};

int main() {
 Parent parent{};
 static constexpr Child child{};
 printf("%s\n", child.name());
}
```

If compiled in VS 2017 with `cl.exe /GL /O1` (that's whole program optimization and optimize for size), it prints Parent. If the line `Parent parent{};` is removed, then the program prints Child.

This problem seems to have been fixed in modern versions of Visual Studio, and in g++. But I want to know whether it's undefined behavior, so that I know whether I can rely on it to work properly going forward.

I would expect it to print Child, because `Parent::name` should call `Child::name2`.

Comment: Seems like it was a bug to me. There's no undefined behaviour.

Comment: I did not observe that behavior. Under VS2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3), the program crashes because the virtual table of `child` is initialized with nulls. But under both VS2017 (15.9.4) and VS2019 (16.10.3), "Child" is printed. Commenting `parent` makes no difference (and it is optimized away).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I expect it's a specific mix of compile flags that does it, or maybe a specific minor version. Did you compile it on the command line, with the line I gave? I'm using 15.9.34 (which is probably the baseline VS 2017 version).

Comment: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizaing Compiler Version 19.16.27045 for x64`

Comment: `virtual const char *name2() const` should be `const char *name2() const override` in Child.

Comment: It should, but that's optional and doesn't change the output for me.

Comment: Yes, I applied these flags.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a compiler bug. The shown code is well-formed, there is no undefined behavior. Just for completeness: gcc 13 prints "Child".